# Altbeacon Library sample doesn't seem to work in the Background

Tags: android, ibeacon, ibeacon-android, android-ibeacon, altbeacon

I have used the basic sample application provided by `Altbeacon` (`Radio Network`) on the Github repo.

Everything seems to work for my iBeacon right from `Monitoring` to the `Ranging` but only in Foreground

I have done these following steps to get it working in Foreground.

```
public class BeaconReferenceApplication extends Application implements BootstrapNotifier, RangeNotifier
{

private static final String TAG = "BeaconReferenceApplication";
private BeaconManager mBeaconManager;
private Region mAllBeaconsRegion;
private BackgroundPowerSaver mBackgroundPowerSaver;
private RegionBootstrap mRegionBootstrap;
private BackgroundPowerSaver backgroundPowerSaver;

@Override
public void onCreate()
{
    mAllBeaconsRegion = new Region(getPackageName(), null, null, null);

    mBeaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);
    mBackgroundPowerSaver = new BackgroundPowerSaver(this);
    mRegionBootstrap = new RegionBootstrap(this, mAllBeaconsRegion);
    mBeaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24"));
    backgroundPowerSaver = new BackgroundPowerSaver(this);
}

@Override
public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Collection<Beacon> arg0, Region arg1)
{
    System.out.println("app-> didRangeBeaconsInRegion");
}

@Override
public void didDetermineStateForRegion(int arg0, Region arg1)
{
    System.out.println("app-> didDetermineStateForRegion");
}

@Override
public void didEnterRegion(Region arg0)
{
    System.out.println("app-> didEnterRegion");
    try
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "entered region.  starting ranging");
        mBeaconManager.setRangeNotifier(this);
        mBeaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(mAllBeaconsRegion);
    }
    catch(RemoteException e)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "Cannot start ranging");
    }

    Intent intentMainActivity = new Intent(this,MonitoringAndRangingActivity.class);
    intentMainActivity.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intentMainActivity);
}

@Override
public void didExitRegion(Region arg0)
{
    System.out.println("app-> didExitRegion");
}

public void setMonitoringAndRangingActivity(MonitoringAndRangingActivity activity)
{
    mBeaconManager.setBackgroundMode((activity==null)?true:false);
}

}
```

`Edit:` I have added the method `mBeaconManager.setBackgroundMode(true);` but no help, i just get the stopLE scan() message from `BlutoothAdapter` and everything stops, do i need to implement this in a Service or anything else?

But as soon as I go to background(pressing back or home) the logs and the `callback methods` stop responding.
Is there anything that i am missing to activate the background iBeacon detection.

Any inputs would be like a boon.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are using the `BackgroundPowerSaver` it will transition the Android Beacon Library into background mode automatically.  There is no need to call `setBackgroundMode` manually.

When the library is in background mode, it only does a scan every 5 minutes to save power (this timing is configurable) so it may take up to five minutes to detect a beacon.  I would watch LogCat for five minutes while your aspp is in the background and see if you get any detections in that time.  If not, adding a LogCat excerpt to your question would be helpful.

Comment: if i walk out of the `Beacon` range keeping the app in background, you are saying i would get a call back in `didExitRegion` for that beacon in about 5 mins? cheers for the prompt reply

Comment: Yes, and again, that interval is configurable with `beaconManager.setBackgroundBetweenScanPeriod(long intervalMilliseconds)`

Comment: thats just great, i will cross check with reduced time for log prints and update you soon.

Comment: yes correct, you are the god of `Beacons!!` Keep it up bro(+1)